# Android Jetpack Compose: how to zoom a image in a "box"?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am going to build a zoomable image view inside a box, like the first screenshot. But when I zoom in on the image, it will go out of the box. Is there a way to zoom the image, but keep the size? Without `view` or `fragment`, only `box` seems not enough. I am expecting the image to get bigger, but still stay inside the red box, but I got the second screenshot after zooming in.

[image: Before zoom in]
[image: After zoom in]

Thanks to nglauber and Amirhosein, I got the final solution with having the zooming and dragging features at the same time inside a "box"(fixed area) with the following code as the new screenshot as shown below.

```
        val imageBitmap = imageResource(id = R.drawable.android)
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .preferredSize(400.dp, 300.dp)
                .clip(RectangleShape)
                .zoomable(onZoomDelta = { scale.value *= it })
                .rawDragGestureFilter(
                    object : DragObserver {
                        override fun onDrag(dragDistance: Offset): Offset {
                            translate.value = translate.value.plus(dragDistance)
                            return super.onDrag(dragDistance)
                        }
                    })
                .graphicsLayer(
                    scaleX = scale.value,
                    scaleY = scale.value,
                    translationX = translate.value.x,
                    translationY = translate.value.y
                ),
            contentDescription = null,
            bitmap = imageBitmap
        )
```

[image]

Comment: Where you able to limit the `translateX` and `translateY` to keep the image within the box?

Comment: `Modifier.clipToBounds()` or `clip(RectangleShape)` would do the job @Bugdr0id

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here is my solution... Might be helpful for someone...

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ZoomableImage() {
    val scale = remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
    val rotationState = remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .clip(RectangleShape) // Clip the box content
            .fillMaxSize() // Give the size you want...
            .background(Color.Gray)
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTransformGestures { centroid, pan, zoom, rotation ->
                    scale.value *= zoom
                    rotationState.value += rotation
                }
            }
    ) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.Center) // keep the image centralized into the Box
                .graphicsLayer(
                    // adding some zoom limits (min 50%, max 200%)
                    scaleX = maxOf(.5f, minOf(3f, scale.value)),
                    scaleY = maxOf(.5f, minOf(3f, scale.value)),
                    rotationZ = rotationState.value
                ),
            contentDescription = null,
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.dog)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: It works for me, even putting it inside `Column` or other layout. Thanks!

Comment: `.clip(RectangleShape)` is the key point I miss! Your version is for zooming only, but not dragging as well.

Comment: Super useful, thank you! Heads up, `rotationState`  should be `0f` initially.

Comment: Just a minor improvement, but more readable and understandable: Instead of `maxOf(min, minOf(max, scale.value))` you could use `scale.value.coerceIn(min, max)`.

Comment: This example doesn't support the pan. How about  pan and zoom?

Answer (score 10):

I have a bit more general solution that supports panning. This is based on the answers provided by nglauber and arun-padiyan.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ZoomableBox(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    minScale: Float = 0.1f,
    maxScale: Float = 5f,
    content: @Composable ZoomableBoxScope.() -> Unit
) {
    var scale by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
    var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    var size by remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero) }
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .clip(RectangleShape)
            .onSizeChanged { size = it }
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTransformGestures { _, pan, zoom, _ ->
                    scale = maxOf(minScale, minOf(scale * zoom, maxScale))
                    val maxX = (size.width * (scale - 1)) / 2
                    val minX = -maxX
                    offsetX = maxOf(minX, minOf(maxX, offsetX + pan.x))
                    val maxY = (size.height * (scale - 1)) / 2
                    val minY = -maxY
                    offsetY = maxOf(minY, minOf(maxY, offsetY + pan.y))
                }
            }
    ) {
        val scope = ZoomableBoxScopeImpl(scale, offsetX, offsetY)
        scope.content()
    }
}

interface ZoomableBoxScope {
    val scale: Float
    val offsetX: Float
    val offsetY: Float
}

private data class ZoomableBoxScopeImpl(
    override val scale: Float,
    override val offsetX: Float,
    override val offsetY: Float
) : ZoomableBoxScope
```

The usage is then something like:

```kotlin
ZoomableBox {
    Image(
        modifier = Modifier
                    .graphicsLayer(
                        scaleX = scale,
                        scaleY = scale,
                        translationX = offsetX,
                        translationY = offsetY
                    ),
        bitmap = bitmap,
        contentDescription = null
    )
}
```

Answer (score 8):

zoomable has deprecated can use `PointerInputScope.detectTransformGestures`

```
@Composable
fun ImagePreview(link: String) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        var angle by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
        var zoom by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
        var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
        var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

        CoilImage(
            data = link,
            contentDescription = "image",
            contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
            modifier = Modifier
                .offset { IntOffset(offsetX.roundToInt(), offsetY.roundToInt()) }
                .graphicsLayer(
                    scaleX = zoom,
                    scaleY = zoom,
                    rotationZ = angle
                )
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectTransformGestures(
                        onGesture = { _, pan, gestureZoom, gestureRotate ->
                            angle += gestureRotate
                            zoom *= gestureZoom
                            val x = pan.x * zoom
                            val y = pan.y * zoom
                            val angleRad = angle * PI / 180.0
                            offsetX += (x * cos(angleRad) - y * sin(angleRad)).toFloat()
                            offsetY += (x * sin(angleRad) + y * cos(angleRad)).toFloat()
                        }
                    )
                }
                .fillMaxSize()
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not zoom out properly , Otherwise its working as expected

Comment: when zoomed maximum

Answer (score 3):

Using Jetpack Compose [AsyncImage](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/#asyncimage) from [coil](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/).
Copied code from [nglauber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1094333/nglauber) and adjusted for my requirements.
Add zoom/pan screen overflow restrictions. No image Rotation.
I didn't want to add dependency just to show an accessible image.

```
@Composable
fun ImagePreview(model: Any, contentDescription: String? = null) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        val angle by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
        var zoom by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
        var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
        var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

        val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
        val screenWidth = configuration.screenWidthDp.dp.value
        val screenHeight = configuration.screenHeightDp.dp.value

        AsyncImage(
            model,
            contentDescription = contentDescription,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
            modifier = Modifier
                .offset { IntOffset(offsetX.roundToInt(), offsetY.roundToInt()) }
                .graphicsLayer(
                    scaleX = zoom,
                    scaleY = zoom,
                    rotationZ = angle
                )
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectTransformGestures(
                        onGesture = { _, pan, gestureZoom, _ ->
                            zoom = (zoom * gestureZoom).coerceIn(1F..4F)
                            if (zoom > 1) {
                                val x = (pan.x * zoom)
                                val y = (pan.y * zoom)
                                val angleRad = angle * PI / 180.0

                                offsetX =
                                    (offsetX + (x * cos(angleRad) - y * sin(angleRad)).toFloat()).coerceIn(
                                        -(screenWidth * zoom)..(screenWidth * zoom)
                                    )
                                offsetY =
                                    (offsetY + (x * sin(angleRad) + y * cos(angleRad)).toFloat()).coerceIn(
                                        -(screenHeight * zoom)..(screenHeight * zoom)
                                    )
                            } else {
                                offsetX = 0F
                                offsetY = 0F
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
                .fillMaxSize()
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using all response this the best result I think, covering :

- double tap zoom
- zoom by gesture
- scroll
- close button

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun ZoomableImage(
    model: Any,
    contentDescription: String? = null,
    onBackHandler: () -> Unit,
) {
    val angle by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    var zoom by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
    var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
    val screenWidth = configuration.screenWidthDp.dp.value
    val screenHeight = configuration.screenHeightDp.dp.value

    BackHandler { onBackHandler() }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Black)
            .combinedClickable(
                interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                indication = null,
                onClick = {},
                onDoubleClick = {
                    zoom = if (zoom > 1f) 1f
                    else 3f
                }
            )
    ) {
        AsyncImage(
            model,
            contentDescription = contentDescription,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
            modifier = Modifier
                .offset { IntOffset(offsetX.roundToInt(), offsetY.roundToInt()) }
                .graphicsLayer(
                    scaleX = zoom,
                    scaleY = zoom,
                    rotationZ = angle
                )
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectTransformGestures(
                        onGesture = { _, pan, gestureZoom, _ ->
                            zoom = (zoom * gestureZoom).coerceIn(1F..4F)
                            if (zoom > 1) {
                                val x = (pan.x * zoom)
                                val y = (pan.y * zoom)
                                val angleRad = angle * PI / 180.0

                                offsetX =
                                    (offsetX + (x * cos(angleRad) - y * sin(angleRad)).toFloat()).coerceIn(
                                        -(screenWidth * zoom)..(screenWidth * zoom)
                                    )
                                offsetY =
                                    (offsetY + (x * sin(angleRad) + y * cos(angleRad)).toFloat()).coerceIn(
                                        -(screenHeight * zoom)..(screenHeight * zoom)
                                    )
                            } else {
                                offsetX = 0F
                                offsetY = 0F
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
                .fillMaxSize()
        )
        IconButton(
            onClick = onBackHandler
        ) {
            Icon(
                modifier = Modifier.size(18.dp),
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_close), // Replace  it
                contentDescription = "Close full screen",
                tint = Color.White
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set `zoomable` and `rawDragGestureFilter` on `Image` instead of `Box` :

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun Zoomable(){
val scale = remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
val translate = remember { mutableStateOf(Offset(0f, 0f)) }

Box(
    modifier = Modifier.preferredSize(300.dp)

) {
    val imageBitmap = imageResource(id = R.drawable.cover)
    Image(
        modifier = Modifier
            .zoomable(onZoomDelta = { scale.value *= it })
            .rawDragGestureFilter(
                object : DragObserver {
                    override fun onDrag(dragDistance: Offset): Offset {
                        translate.value = translate.value.plus(dragDistance)
                        return super.onDrag(dragDistance)
                    }
                })
            .graphicsLayer(
                scaleX = scale.value,
                scaleY = scale.value,
                translationX = translate.value.x,
                translationY = translate.value.y
            ),
        contentDescription = null,
        bitmap = imageBitmap
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it still works the same way with your change, going out of the box when zooming in.

Comment: Do you set a static size for  `Box`?

Comment: Yes, I even copy your code into my project, but it still works the same. Does it work for you, zooming staying inside the box?

Comment: I am using Jetpack Compose `1.0.0-alpha11` anyway.

Comment: I figure out why. I put the `Box` inside a `Column`, that's why it stop working. If just a box as a `root` layout, it works. But it still doesn't make any sense for breaking the `Box` just because of putting it inside the other layout.

Comment: Then, remove the box (if you are not using any functionalities it provides) and set a static size for `Image`. It works for me (`1.0.0-alpha11`)

Comment: Nice solution, but some tweaks are missing. How to limit the dragging to not leave the screen? With current solution, user is able to completely drag the image out of the square.

Comment: This solution is outdated `rawDragGestureFilter` is deprecated