# How to have Image zoom in Jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

Image zoom like of Instagram in jetpack compose if anyone can help

I want something like this
https://drive.google.com/file/d/18a7SaPIoSObbvrmYxJ0GDhHXEETKpsEV/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Similar questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66005066/android-jetpack-compose-how-to-zoom-a-image-in-a-box some other tutorials https://proandroiddev.com/zoomable-image-with-jetpack-compose-13b050675da5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1- save the scale as a state

```
var scale by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
```

2- Set the scale of your image to use this state. I recommend using graphicsLayer to set the scale in order to minimize the invalidated content, and add any other transformations you want like the following

```
Image(
        ...,
        modifier = Modifier
            .graphicsLayer(
                scaleX = scale,
                scaleY = scale
            )
    )
```

3- Use `Modifier.pointerInput` to detect and apply the zoom effect. with the PointerInputScope you can detect tabs and transformations namely (zoom, rotation and pan). For example you can add the following to detect zoom gestures and modify the scale accordingly.

```
modifier = Modifier
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTransformGestures { _, _, zoom, _ ->
                    scale = when {
                        scale < 0.5f -> 0.5f
                        scale > 3f -> 3f
                        else -> scale * zoom
                    }
                }
            }
```

the other parameters of `detectTransformGestures` are centroid, pan and rotation. you don't need them for the zoom transformation but you will if you tried to apply rotation and translation.

If you want to apply the zoom using pan gesture you can use the `detectTapGestures`. here is an example.

```
modifier = Modifier
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTapGestures(
                    onDoubleTap = {
                        scale = when {
                            scale > 2f -> 1f
                            else -> 3f
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
```

Here is a complete sample using CoilImage. the implementation should be the same for any other Image

```
@Composable fun SamplePreview(imageUrl: String) {
var scale by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
Box {
    CoilImage(
        data = imageUrl,
        contentDescription = null,
        contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth,
        modifier = Modifier
            .align(Alignment.Center)
            .graphicsLayer(
                scaleX = scale,
                scaleY = scale
            )
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTransformGestures { _, _, zoom, _ ->
                    scale = when {
                        scale < 0.5f -> 0.5f
                        scale > 3f -> 3f
                        else -> scale * zoom
                    }
                }
            }
    ) {
        CircularProgressIndicator()
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `.graphicsLayer` with the lamdba version. It updates the composable without triggering recomposition and relayout. Something like: `.graphicsLayer{ scaleX = scale; scaleY = scale}`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti the change you proposed sounds good, but unfortunately it doesn't work. If you have working code for that I'd be pleased to try it :-) thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the working code Mostafa. A small improvement: Instead of using `when`, you can replace it with: `scale = (scale * zoom).coerceIn(0.5f, 3f)` and it'll work exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

Did you make any progress? I am able to zoom the image, but I can't restore the image to the original size when user terminates the gesture.
To zoom the image what I did was:
Created a scale and state variables. The `if(scale < 1)` is to not let the user minimize the image.

```
var scale by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
val state = rememberTransformableState { zoomChange, _, _ ->
                scale *= zoomChange
                if(scale < 1){
                    scale = 1F
                }
        }
```

In the image, I used the graphicsLayer and the transformable.

```
.graphicsLayer{
                    scaleX = scale;
                    scaleY = scale
                }
.transformable(state = state)
```

I tried to capture the MotionEvent of the user, but didn't find a MotionEvent that observed the pinch gesture.
Also, in the `.pointerInput` I can't use `detectTapGestures` and `detectTransformGestures` together, because the pointer just considers one.