# Android Compose Zoom out gesture not detected

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am using jetpack compose and I have a picture that i want to zoom and pan. The suggested solution in the answer of this ([Android Jetpack Compose: how to zoom a image in a "box"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66005066/android-jetpack-compose-how-to-zoom-a-image-in-a-box)) thread works in general, however zooming out is not detected when both fingers are placed in a vertical or diagonal line. More concretely the lambda of `detectTransformestures` is not called in that case:

```
Image(
    modifier = Modifier
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTransformGestures(panZoomLock = true) { _, pan, zoom, _ ->
                //not called for vertical zoom-in
            }
        },
    bitmap = bitmap,
    contentDescription = null,
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
)
```

Weirdly enough it *is* called when the entire gesture is started with a zoom-in, that works as expected also with a vertical zoom. However, when trying to start a gesture by zooming out nothing happens. Is this intentional? It feels very weird and unexpected...

Comment: Implementing the whole zooming logic is quite complex. Check out this library, it works nicely for me: https://github.com/mxalbert1996/Zoomable

Comment: I also have the same problem. Did you find any solution to this?